# Pegar domínio com o PHP utiizando parse_url

Tags: php, url

Preciso verificar se a pagina acessada esta no domínio `.com.br` ou `.fr`.

Pensei em utilizar a função `parse_url` porém não obtive sucesso, como pegar somente a parte `.com.br` ou `.fr`.

Por exemplo se o dominio é.

```
https://www.exemplo.com.br
```

Ele me retorna `www.exemplo.com.br` pegando o `PHP_URL_HOST`
Eu precisava que pegasse só p `.com.br`

E o mesmo vale para o dominio

```
https://www.exemplo.fr
```

Pegar somente o `.fr`

Comment: A informação `.com.br` ou `.fr` fazem parte do host, a função faz seu papel corretamente. Você precisa manipular a string para extrair o resultado que você precisa, porém precisa pensar em aspectos que podem complicar. Ex: você pode separar por ponto e remover os 2 primeiros elementos. Assim `www.exemplo.com.br` ficaria `com.br`, mas essa mesma lógica não se aplica se a URL tiver subdomínios com mais profundidade. Ex.: `static.app.exemplo.com.br` ficar `exemplo.com.br`, que não é o resultado que você espera. Então sugiro esclarecer para nós qual sua ideia de resposta ideal para ajudarmos.

Comment: Após pegar a url completa da forma como você já consegue fazer, utilize o a função `explode()` para quebrar sua string em todos os lugares que tem pontos, essa função vai te retornar uma array de strings, se você pegar a última posição, pode verificar se é .fr ou .br...
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: Outra forma também é verificar se `.fr` faz parte do resultado do `parse_url` utilizando o comando `preg_match()`

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente o que você quis dizer não sei porque fecharam a pergunta. De toda forma já saí do computador após posto a resposta se reabirirem a pergunta ou posto como comentário.

Comment: Já tentou http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php#83828 ?

Comment: @LuizFernando pode mandar como comentario.

Comment: ```<?php
$url = "https://www.php.br";
echo " A url é: $url\n";
echo "\nO tipo de domínio da URL é: " . getSufixoUrl($url);
function getSufixoUrl($url) {
    $explode_url = explode(".", $url, 3);
    $count = count($explode_url);

    if ($count === 3) {
        $tipo_dominio = "." . $explode_url[2];
    } elseif ($count === 2) {
        $tipo_dominio = "." . $explode_url[1];
    }
    return $tipo_dominio;
}``` A função considera que o domínio  seja www.exemplo.com. Senão colocar o www, você tem que alterar os valores. Caso queira restringir só .com.br e .fr mude no retorno tbm